# Coffeescript - React callback: sending child header click back to parent

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

Just starting to learn Coffeescript, and I'm working with React.js. I'm trying to determine which  was clicked, and I've been advised not to use data-attributes on each header. I have some ideas how to handle this under the handleHeaderClick function, but I'm not exactly sure how they should be implemented. I'm also thinking about splitting up the ContactsTable component into a ContactsTableHeader component and a ContactsTableRow component, but I should still have the same issue in ContactsTableHeader - determining which header was clicked.

```
#Application.cjsx

handleHeaderClick: ->
   # childComponent.props
   # childComponent.refs
   # React.findDOMNode(childComponent.refs.firstName)
   # React.findDOMNode(childComponent.refs.lastName)
   # React.findDOMNode(childComponent.refs.age)

render: ->
  <div>
    <ContactsTable contactList={@state.contacts} onClick={@handleHeaderClick} />
  </div>



#ContactsTable.cjsx

render: ->
  if @props.contactList
    contactsList = @props.contactList.map (contact) ->
                <tr><td>{"#{contact.firstName}"}</td><td>{"#{contact.lastName}"}</td><td>{contact.age}</td></tr>


  <table style={tableStyle}>
    <thead style={headerStyle} onClick=@props.onClick>
        <tr>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {contactsList}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. I assume that you will click a `th` which is either "First Name", "Last Name" or "Age". And you want to capture which header was clicked?

Comment: @DeepakPrasanna Exactly! Sorry, the header tag in the first line of my description got cut out.

Comment: Can you let me know if my answer helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
#Application.cjsx

handleHeaderClick: (header) ->
  @setState({clickedHeader: header})
  #do something else

render: ->
  <div>
    <ContactsTable contactList={@state.contacts} onClick={@handleHeaderClick} />
  </div>



#ContactsTable.cjsx

render: ->
  if @props.contactList
    contactsList = @props.contactList.map (contact) ->
                <tr><td>{"#{contact.firstName}"}</td><td>{"#{contact.lastName}"}</td><td>{contact.age}</td></tr>


  <table style={tableStyle}>
    <thead style={headerStyle}>
        <tr>
            <th onClick={@props.onClick('FirstName')}>FirstName</th>
            <th onClick={@props.onClick('LastName')}>Last Name</th>
            <th onClick={@props.onClick('Age')}>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {contactsList}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here the clickedHeader is preserved inside the component which is present in Application.cjsx. You can also preserve it inside `ContactsTableHeader` which should look something like similar.